# Can a Synthesist Summoner with a multi-armed eidolon get the multiweapon fighting monster feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feat-qualifications

Can a [Synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist) whose eidolon has multiples of the evolution [limbs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons/#TOC-Limbs-Ex-) (arms) pick up the monster feat [Multiweapon Fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/multiweapon-fighting-combat)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find anything in the RAW directly supporting or prohibiting this, so ultimately it's the DM's call (unless I've missed something).

**However**, I think a case can be made for taking the feat:

The only prerequisites for *Multiweapon Fighting* are "Dex 13, three or more hands.".
If your eidolon takes *Limbs (arms)* twice, your Synthesist would have 4 arms while fused with it. Assuming your eidolon also has Dex 13 or more, then you will meet the prerequisites, **but only while fused with the eidolon**.

Now, if you already had the feat, the fact that you occasionally don't meet the requirements (i.e. when not fused, you don't have the requisite number of hands), wouldn't cause you to lose it, just render you unable to use it:

> A character can't use a feat if he loses a prerequisite, but he does not lose the feat itself. If, at a later time, he regains the lost prerequisite, he immediately regains full use of the feat that prerequisite enables.

So this boils down to: **can you learn this feat even though you don't qualify *all* the time?**  - this is up to the DM, but there is a precedence with gaining ranks in the *Fly* skill:

> [...] **Requirement**
>   You cannot take this skill without a natural means of flight or gliding. Creatures can also take ranks in Fly **if they possess a reliable means of flying every day** (either through a spell or other magical manner, such as a druid’s wild shape ability).

Your question concerns a feat, not a skill, but it seems that since you can remain in the fused state as long as you are awake, it should count as a **reliable means** for training for this feat.